# Best method of checking a value in ranges in android?

Tags: java, android, collections, stack

I'm designing a roulette app. I need a way to take my ending rotation, "wheelRotateTo" and find out, in a list of degrees, which are currently in a stack of 36 "segments" on the wheel.

So if the end degree is 355, it should identify the last stack object, because it's `< 360`, but greater than the degree of the segment below it..

Likewise, if wheelRotateTo was 339, it should give me the second stack segment down, because it fits there.

This is just driving me crazy. Can someone explain a reasonable way to identify which segment or "Wheel number" it stops on?

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with `if (lowerBound < value && value < upperBound)`?

Comment: Alternatively, I think you can do `maxValue / sectionSize` to give you the number of sections and `value / sectionSize` to give you the index of the section for `value`

Comment: Is there a way to search a stack like that? Because dividing the result by the segment size returns a float, and im looking for an integer between 0  and 36, inclusive

Comment: I don't know about a stack. Maybe an array because you can directly get the indexes. But you can do integer division to truncate the float. For example `Math.floor(355 / 10) = 35`

Comment: I assume you are just dealing with a wheel of 360 degrees and 36 "sections", with each section being 10 "degrees" wide? I've played roulette, but I want to make sure that is your data model

Comment: You are correct, except the segments are technically 9.7 degrees

Comment: @cricket_007 In the case of `int`s, `Math.floor()` is unnecessary.

Comment: What is your "list of degrees"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Well the stack I packed, starts from the top with 360, 350, 340.

Comment: The actual ranges are, 0 - 9.73, 9.74 - 19.46, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of several solutions:

1. Divide the number of degrees by the number of degrees per section. This will give you the index for the section in your list.
2. Don't worry about degrees at all. Just randomly generate an index to your list.

Comment: Could you elaborate on #2 please. And #1 seems to be the way to go from what im gathering.

Comment: @user5890577 If your wheel has 36 "segments", you can choose a random number between 0 and 35 inclusively.

Comment: Ahh, I have a rand as a placeholder right now, until I could read the wheel result. I have a wheel and ball image that spin, opposite, and the ball stops a bit after the wheel. End game is to get the final ball position on the wheel at the end of spin. Step one is reading a degree from wheel or ball, and relating it to a segment

Comment: @user5890577 Is each "section" exactly 10 degrees? Or are some bigger and some smaller?

Comment: They are all exactly 9.7 degrees

Comment: @That makes things a little more complicated. Since you need to have the number of degrees for your animation, you will probably need to use option #1. Also, since you are doing floating point division, you will need to use `Math.floor()` to round down to the nearest integer.

Comment: Okay, i used: int wheelVari = (int) (rotateTo/9.7) it reads fine, and returns the correct segment it pointing at the zero position. Perfect. But the main thing I need to solve, and my question I guess, is how to make a list of the segments, based on wheelVari being the first. I need this because I need to see which segment the ball stops on, and that segment obviously changes because the wheel spins too.

Comment: @user5890577 What do you mean "list of segments"?

Comment: Okay, let me try to explain how I think this needs to work.

Comment: So,  the numbers printed on the wheel, do not go in order. So if I can populate some type of list, in a specified order, where the segment the wheel stopped at (its top position) and count from there, to where the ball lands, I should be able to figure out which segment (and then which number) the ball has stopped on

Comment: Okay, I solved thus with math. So now the app actually figures out which number on the wheel, the ball stopped on. All I need now is a way to get variables I set for each wheel position,  like winning bet spots, color

Comment: @user5890577 If you need further help, please start a new question.